# Constant in linear regression a vector of 1s?

Tags: r, lm

I overheard a comment that the y-intercept in linear regression is called constant because it contains a vector of 1s. Is there a way this can be demonstrated in R? I have searched far and wide for an example and explanation but I keep coming up short.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A great way to see this concept is by inspecting the output from [`model.matrix`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/model.matrix.html), which constructs a design matrix.

For example, using the `mtcars` dataset, we can see a column full of 1s for the `(Intercept)`:

```
model.matrix(wt ~ mpg + hp, data = mtcars)

                    (Intercept)  mpg  hp
Mazda RX4                     1 21.0 110
Mazda RX4 Wag                 1 21.0 110
Datsun 710                    1 22.8  93
Hornet 4 Drive                1 21.4 110
Hornet Sportabout             1 18.7 175
Valiant                       1 18.1 105
Duster 360                    1 14.3 245
...
```

Another way to see this concept is to set `x = TRUE` in `lm`:

```
f1 <- lm(wt ~ mpg + hp, data = mtcars, x = TRUE)
f1$x

                    (Intercept)  mpg  hp
Mazda RX4                     1 21.0 110
Mazda RX4 Wag                 1 21.0 110
Datsun 710                    1 22.8  93
Hornet 4 Drive                1 21.4 110
Hornet Sportabout             1 18.7 175
Valiant                       1 18.1 105
...
```